# Select fields where "true" and order by priority

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have several events that are `true/false` for a customer. Secondly, I have prioritized the events from `1 - 4`.

[image]

When selecting a customer I would like to receive only the events that are true by a customer in the specific order:

[image]

So for example:

If I select customer with ID 1, I would like to get `Event 3` and `Event 1` back as they are `true` for this customer in the specified order. (`Event 3` is on the 1st place and `Event 1` is on the 2nd place.

You can find an example [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19OgNd_Fs0yPpwXtAMUAqNinFcUbvvnxN4Enq384edP8/edit?usp=sharing) here.

With 4 Events I could do several `IF's` and display the correct value in the first row. However, in reality, I have over `500 Events` and `>5000 customers`.

At the moment I am missing an idea of how to approach this problem.

Any suggestion on how to display the prioritized events per user?

Comment: its not rly clear what takes priority before what and what exactly are you after

Comment: @player0 Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in cell E15 and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({$A3:$A10, IF($B3:$E10=TRUE, $B2:$E2, )}, 
 "where Col1="&E14, 0)), "where Col1 is not null offset 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]